# juju deploy not installing juju agent

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

**Versions**

- Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS
- juju 1.24.4
- maas 1.8.0+bzr4001

**Steps**

- MAAS installed
- nodes commisioned and ready
- local copy of tools and charms created
- ran "juju bootstrap --upload-tools --debug" on MAAS
- node bootstraps but then reports "/var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist"
- ssh on to machine 0 and create nonce.txt with contents of "user-admin:bootstrap"
- bootstrap then continues and sucessfully completes
- run"juju deploy --repository=/home/keith/charms local:trusty/mysql --debug"
- juju status is then stuck at pending/allocating/Waiting for agent initialization to finish. see output below
- can ssh to machine 1
- MAAS, machine 0 and 1 can all sucessfully ping each other using public-address
- There are no machine 1 logs on machine 0 (juju)
- There are no juju logs on machine 1
- Same behaviour for other charms
- Charms deploy sucessfuly if deployed to already running machine 0 using the --to=0

juju status output

```
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.24.4.1
    dns-name: gracious-rabbits.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-8af709d4-3b82-11e5-8107-005056bc64c7/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1024M
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state: pending
    dns-name: first-circle.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-468e9dac-3b87-11e5-89b6-005056bc64c7/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1024M
services:
  mysql:
    charm: local:trusty/mysql-326
    exposed: false
    service-status:
      current: unknown
      message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish
      since: 13 Aug 2015 22:29:26+01:00
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mysql
    units:
      mysql/0:
        workload-status:
          current: unknown
          message: Waiting for agent initialization to finish
          since: 13 Aug 2015 22:29:26+01:00
        agent-status:
          current: allocating
          since: 13 Aug 2015 22:29:26+01:00
        agent-state: pending
        machine: "1"
        public-address: first-circle.maas
networks:
  maas-eth0:
    provider-id: maas-eth0
    cidr: 192.168.248.0/24
```

environments.yaml

```
default: maas
environments:
    maas:
        type: maas
        maas-server: 'http://192.168.248.2/MAAS/'
        maas-oauth: 'vwxwGddnHH7KNwVZwy:NPezs7Gr2M4Zx6qSEd:F5QXRdnTcntPLcmq6dK2Mxd8mphwR9p4'
        authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
        bootstrap-timeout: 600
        admin-secret: xxxxxxx
        agent-metadata-url: http://192.168.248.2/tools
```

cloud-init-ouput.log from machine 1
http://pastebin.com/i2VPpcnv

Please help and many thanks.

Comment: Retried with juju 1.22.6 and no issues with that earlier release.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for raising this issue.  To track status, please check the [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1485071).

Additionally, I am curious if you observe this with Juju 1.24.5?

That is the current version available in the [Juju stable ppa](https://launchpad.net/~juju/+archive/ubuntu/stable).